# What determines maximum local datagram size? (PF_UNIX / SOCK_DGRAM)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

Can local message-based sockets transfer messages up to the SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF limits, or where can the so-called 'fixed maximum length' be determined for a descriptor created with `socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)` or `socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `man unix`

The SO_SNDBUF socket option does have an effect for Unix  domain  sock‐
       ets,  but  the  SO_RCVBUF  option  does not.  For datagram sockets, the
       SO_SNDBUF value imposes an upper limit on the size  of  outgoing  data‐
       grams.   This limit is calculated as the doubled (see socket(7)) option
       value less 32 bytes used for overhead.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thanks!  My RHEL4-based box didn't have anything in the 'unix', 'un.h', or any of the socket-related man pages (all dated late '02/early '03), so I gave up looking a bit prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Your datagrams will be queued in the socket send/receive buffers up to a maximum of SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF respectively. Datagrams will be **discarded** past this limit.

Note that datagrams do not have the exact size of the data you put in them.

I don't really remember, but I think you can tweak those settings. It's always wiser, though, to do your own buffering when dealing with UDP sockets.

edit: sorry about that, right you are. This might be of use:

> The SO_SNDBUF socket option does have
>   an effect for Unix  domain  sock-
>          ets,  but  the  SO_RCVBUF  option  does not.  For datagram
>   sockets, the
>          SO_SNDBUF value imposes an upper limit on the size  of  outgoing 
>   data-
>          grams.   This limit is calculated as the doubled (see
>   socket(7)) option
>          value less 32 bytes used for overhead

Comment: These aren't UDP sockets.  PF_UNIX (AF_UNIX) rather than PF_INET or PF_INET6 (AF_INET or AF_INET6)